# How to hide/show custom title layout when scrolling webview

Tags: android, webview

I want to know how to implement the feature like hiding/showing address bar in Chrome or actionbar in Google Plus.

I have a customized title layout, I want it to be hidden when scrolling webview down and be shown when scrolling up.

The following is the xml file of my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/article_title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/date_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#535353"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:paddingRight="5dip"
                android:text="4/10"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/year"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:paddingRight="5dip"
                android:text="2013"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#0B729D" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/title_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/date_layout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingRight="10dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/category"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="subtitle" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/ad_layout"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_layout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to hiding/showing title bar:

Put your Title part Layout into the ActionBar,then you can use .hide()/.show() when you need.

Set XML file to Actionbar:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActionBar()
    .getThemedContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View customActionBarView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_XML_FILE, null);

ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(
    ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM,
    ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME
            | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
actionBar.setCustomView(customActionBarView,
    new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I already use action bar to show other information, such as share or favorite. Thus, I need other way to implement it.

Comment: Custom actionbar is a simple way..Maybe you can set 2x height to show more information,But it can't separately control like google plus.

Comment: Or maybe you need use this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html